# Started to get error 503 when streaming data to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I"m streaming data to BigQuery 300 rows around 3 times per minute. The insert stopped working a week ago with this error:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem. [503]
>   Errors [
>       Message[Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem.] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]
>   ]

My service worked fine for 2 months and there are no code changes since we started to use it.

Here is the code that calls BigQuery:

```
public async Task<TableDataInsertAllResponse> Update(List<TableDataInsertAllRequest.RowsData> rows, string tableSuffix)
{
    var request = new TableDataInsertAllRequest {Rows = rows, TemplateSuffix = tableSuffix};
    var insertRequest = mBigqueryService.Tabledata.InsertAll(request, ProjectId, mDatasetId, mTableId);

    return await insertRequest.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

Anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: do you have a project id so the team can debug?

Comment: The project id is solutohome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general 503 means 'a temporary server failure such as a network connection problem or a server overload.'
See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

However in your case, it seems like your project disabled the billing. The actual error msg should be 'billingNotEnabled'.

We'll fix the error msg soon. Thanks for reporting!